# How do I get the client to authenticate first?

Tags: security, ssl

I need a security protocol where the client authenticates before the server. This is necessary because its a matter of privacy. I dont want any unknown party to know who they are connecting to unless they are allowed to know. In the TLS protocol, the server send his cert first thereby eliminating this possibility. I know enough to know that implementing my own protocol is a bad idea. However, is there a choice? I.e. is there a way to alter the protocol to send the certs in the other order? Wikipidea reference to TLS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake

Comment: why are you trying to do this?  could you just make a really obscure self-signed cert, and trust that cert on your clients instead?

Comment: @jglouie The problem is that the certs contain identifiable information (as that is the purpose of the cert) and any random person should not have the ability to identify the user

Comment: You can put bogus identifying data in a self-signed cert.  will that approach work, or do you require a "real" cert whose CA is already trusted by the client?

Comment: @jglouie I require a real cert

Comment: How strong of authentication is required before you could consider letting the server authenticate itself?  Port knocking is a simple system to implement (iptables).  It forces a client to first provide the 'password' before he can connect over SSL.

Comment: @Daisetsu Ideally the client would send his cert first, then the server would check the identity, and if allowed, send an encrypted response (with the public key provided by the cert)

Comment: @chacham15, I would require "client" certificate authentication for this (when the TLS client is the TCP server), since otherwise, the (actual TCP) client would have no idea that it really is talking to the server it wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse the roles of the client and server.

Normally, with TCP, the client is the endpoint that did `connect()` (and send a SYN) and the server is the endpoint that did `accept()` (it received the SYN and sent back a SYN|ACK). But once the connection is established, there is no longer any difference between the client's socket and the server's socket.

If you're using, say, OpenSSL, you normally call `SSL_connect()` after a successful `connect()` and you normally call `SSL_accept()` after a successful `accept()`. But if you flip that around and call `SSL_accept()` after `connect()` on the client side and call `SSL_connect()` after `accept()` on the server side, OpenSSL will never know the difference. And the client will behave as a TLS server and identify itself first.

Comment: Wouldn't that not allow the client to check the servers credentials? Im sorry this is a bit confusing, could you explain it a little more? Thanks!

Comment: The server can present its certificate after the client has done it first, just like in normal TLS but backwards.

Comment: +1. As the [TLS RFC says](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346#appendix-B): "*client*: 
      The application entity that initiates a TLS connection to a
      server.  This may or may not imply that the client initiated the
      underlying transport connection.  The primary operational
      difference between the server and client is that the server is
      generally authenticated, while the client is only optionally
      authenticated."